# Markdown Editing Editor Center

Tags: markdown, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I have installed the markdown editing plugin. When I edit a md File the curser is in the middle of the editor page. How can I get the cursor to the left?

regards,
Marko

### Update

Markdown Editing Plugin Page

- https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/MarkdownEditing

Comment: Which plugin are you using? There are several, please include its exact name and URL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found the solution in the buglist of the plugins github profile.

https://github.com/SublimeText-Markdown/MarkdownEditing/issues/183

Preferences > Package Settings > MarkdownEditing > Markdown GFM Settings - User:

```
"draw_centered": false,
```

Here is another helpful site

- http://www.javatronic.fr/2014/01/10/tuning_sublime_for_markdown_editing.html